# Priority Queue in Java, ordering method

Tags: java, priority-queue, heap

If I am using a Priority Queue (in Java) of nodes, every node has a few fields, one of them is frequency. The heap comparator is comparing between the frequencies of the nodes, putting the maximum at the top.
My question is as follows: if I'm changing the inner state of let's say the top node in the heap (decrmenting it's frequency field) and it is no longer the "maximal" node in the heap according to the comparing rules- does the heap should change itself  and reorder the nodes?
In other words, does the Priority Queue compares between it's nodes only at the time of the insertion or also whenever the nodes change their inner state?

At first i thought that changing the inner state of the heap's nodes will cause the heap to reorganize itself, but as I observed weird behaviour I am thinking this is not the case.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

> does the heap should change itself and reorder the nodes? In other words, does the Priority Queue compares between it's nodes only at the time of the insertion or also whenever the nodes change their inner state?

No, it does not change.  There is no way for the priority queue to detect the updates and determine that things should be changed.